# Update & DoDraw method to spawn multiple of the same sprite

Tags: java, android, loops, sprite

I'm trying to spawn multiple versions of the same sprite. Each spawns with a random speed (using random numbers between minus and positive speeds to determine random direction) and I have created 2 for loops to load an arraylist with new sprites. However, it seems to spawn 5 sprites, but then it seems like they're deleting and creating 5 more over and over. Below are the methods used:

```
public void update(){ 
        spritesArrayList.clear(); 
        if (gameOver != true) 
        { 

        sprite.update(); 
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        { 
        sprite = new Sprite(this); 
        spritesArrayList.add(sprite); 
        } 
        }
    /**
     * To draw the game to the screen
     * This is called from Thread, so synchronisation can be done
     */

    public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         Paint textPaint = new Paint();

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
        //Draw all the objects on the canvas
        canvas.drawText("The Game ",5,25, paint);
        canvas.drawText("Score: " + hitCount, 5, 50, paint);
        canvas.drawText("Time: " +displayTime, 5, 75, paint);
        GetArrayListSize();

         //Loop for sprite creation
         for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) 
         {          
            Sprite sprite = spritesArrayList.get(i);
            sprite.draw(canvas);

         }


        if (gameOver == true)
        {
            canvas.drawText("Final Score: "+finalScore, 5,100, paint);
            int width = this.getMeasuredWidth()/2;
            int height = this.getMeasuredHeight()/2;
            textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            canvas.drawText("GAME OVER - PRESS BACK BUTTON TO RETURN", width, height, textPaint);
        }

    }
```